# Cakephp Remove plugin and controller name from url for any action

Tags: cakephp, routes

I want to remove deal/deals for all the actions of deals controller:

http://example.com/deal/deals/voucher/dsfsdfdf should be http://example.com/voucher/cPH5aGr1

etc.

Comment: need more information than that

Comment: 1. What version? 2. Read about [Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) _(assuming version 2)_ 3. Try something, then share your code and why it did not work.

Comment: I have done it buy appling routing for each action separetly like: Router::connect('/deal_listing/*', array('plugin'=>'deal' , 'controller' => 'deals', 'action' => 'deal_listing'));
 Router::connect('/deal/add/*', array('plugin'=>'deal' , 'controller' => 'deals', 'action' => 'add'));
 Router::connect('/business/add/*', array('plugin'=>'deal' , 'controller' => 'business', 'action' => 'add'));  Is there any way by which I don't have to write separate line for each action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define you routes in you app/config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/voucher/*', array('controller' => 'Deals', 'action' => 'voucher', 'plugin' => 'Deal'));
```